# Nested Quantifiers - true or false

Tags: discrete-mathematics, quantifiers

I was just wondering what the truth value is for:

$\exists y \forall x (x^2 < y + 1)$. The domain of discourse is: $R$ X $R$.

The reason I believe this is false is x = y = 0. Which makes the condition $(x^2 < y + 1)$ false. Am I right?

$\forall y \exists x (x^2 < y + 1)$. The domain of discourse is: $R$ X $R$.

The reason I believe the second one is false once again is x = y = 0. Which makes the condition $(x^2 < y + 1)$ false. Am I right?

I'm sorry I'm new to this and I just am not sure of my answers... thank you for your help

Comment: It is indeed false, but the argument is not correct. You need to show that given **any** fixed $y$, say $b$, there is an $x$ such that $x^2\ge b+1$.

Comment: For the second problem, let $y=-1$, or $-\pi$, or $-77$.

Answer (score 2):

For the first, the problem with your reasoning is this: you're basically saying that there is a $y$ for which it is not true.  That doesn't mean that there couldn't exist a $y$ for which it IS true -- and that's what you're asked to consider!

If you want to show that the result "$\exists y\forall x(x^2<y+1)$" is false, you need to show that for EVERY $y$, the result "$\forall x(x^2<y+1)$" is false. Does that make sense?

For the second: again your result is correct, but your reasoning is no good!  If you want to show that the result "$\forall y\exists x(x^2<y+1)$" is false, you need to show that there exists a $y$ such that "$\exists x(x^2<y+1)$" is false.

Comment: I honestly do not understand the way you result to numbers to prove that the quantifier is true or false...

Comment: @Elmer You can make $x^2$ as large as you want by choosing $x$, yes?  So if I give you any number $y$, I bet you can choose $x$ large enough that $x^2\geq y+1$. So, this $x$ would not satisfy $x^2<y+1$, and therefore proves that the statement "$\forall x(x^2<y+1)$" is false for the given $y$.  But you can do this for every $y$, which proves that there doesn't exist $y$ such that $x^2<y+1$ for all $x$.  The other case is more straight-forward (and Andre Nicolas gave you a good hint in the comments).

Comment: So you are saying for the second one, if y = 1 and x = 1, wouldn't that be valid and make it true?

Comment: @Elmer You showed that when $y=1$, "$\exists x(x^2<y+1)$" is a true statement.  Have you shown that it is true __for every $y$__?